# Getting processed data after stored procedure call

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

```
//1. inserting data into the db
_context.MyModel.AddRange(content);
_context.SaveChanges();

//2. calling a stored procedure for data process
_context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("CALL process_data()");

//3. getting back processed data - not working, getting pre-processed data instead
List<MyModel> processedContent = _context.MyModel.ToList();
```

I'm having a problem fetching processed data from step 2. in step 3. - the data I keep getting back is the one I inserted in step 1. (the pre-processed data) while I want to get stored procedure processed data.

I've put a break point on step 3., and run a query on the db - and yes, all the processed data is there. It seems like the `_context` doesn't get updated with new data.

Any clue what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: have you tried "var results = _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("CALL process_data()");"

Comment: try to _context.SaveChanges(); method after executing Stored Procedure.

Comment: @Tan the `ExecuteSqlRaw` query just returns number of rows affected as an int.
@ParamjotSingh thanks, but I've tried that, it didn't solve the problem. 

After I created a new db context for fetching data I got my processed data back. So that adds to my theory that the `_context` needs refreshing.

Comment: Can you try to add a debug point tehre and check if there is more data then just an int.

Comment: @Tan it only returns an int: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.executesqlraw?view=efcore-3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I've got for now is to instantiate a new context:

```
//1. inserting data into the db
_context.MyModel.AddRange(content);
_context.SaveChanges();

//2. calling a stored procedure for data process
_context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("CALL process_data()");

MyDbContext _newContext = new MyDbContext(_configuration);

//3. getting back processed data - working fine with new db context
List<MyModel> processedContent = _newContext.MyModel.ToList();
```

The other solution involves refreshing each entry inside the `_context` using:

```
foreach (var c in content)
{
   _context.Entry(c).Reload();
}
```

This works but it's not performance friendly.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce the problem, see the code below. Although EF Core's DbContext indeed retains state, every time you execute `ToList` (or almost any other query operation), your query is executed and the latest results are fetched. A notable exception is `Find`, which will return tracked entity instances without querying the database.

If you still have issues, try changing the full sample below to demonstrate what isn't working.

```cs
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await using var ctx = new BlogContext();
        await ctx.Database.EnsureDeletedAsync();
        await ctx.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();

        await ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(@"
CREATE PROCEDURE process_data()
    LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
    INSERT INTO ""Blogs"" (""Name"") VALUES ('Inserted from stored procedure');
$$;
");

        ctx.Blogs.Add(new Blog { Name = "Original" });
        await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();

        ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("CALL process_data()");

        await foreach (var blog in ctx.Blogs)
            Console.WriteLine(blog.Name);
    }
}

public class BlogContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }

    static ILoggerFactory ContextLoggerFactory
        => LoggerFactory.Create(b => b.AddConsole().AddFilter("", LogLevel.Information));

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        => optionsBuilder
            .UseNpgsql(@"...")
            .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
            .UseLoggerFactory(ContextLoggerFactory);
}

public class Blog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```